# Can't pre-fetch data with resolver on angular 7

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm having issues to pre fetch API data, but i don't seem to get it right. The route is still activated before the data is fetched. I'm trying to use a resolver service in angular 7 to load a list of users.

Here you have my route resolver on the routing module:

```
`const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'list', 
    component: ShowListComponent, 
    resolve: {personList: ResolverService}
  },
  {path: 'add', component: AddComponent},
  {path: 'edit', component: EditComponent},
  {path: 'edit/:id', component: EditComponent}
];`
```

This is where I'm invoking my resolver:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {ServiceService} from '../../Service/service.service';
import { Person } from 'src/app/Model/Person';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-list',
  templateUrl: './show-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-list.component.css']
})
export class ShowListComponent implements OnInit {

  persons:Person[];
  constructor(private service:ServiceService, private aRoute: ActivatedRoute ) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Invoking resolver service
    this.persons = this.aRoute.snapshot.data['personList'];

  }
}
```

This is my resolver service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Person } from '../Model/Person';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { ServiceService } from './service.service';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResolverService implements Resolve<Person[]> {


  constructor(private _persons: ServiceService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Person[]> | Observable<never> {
    return this._persons.getPersons();      
  }
}
```

And finally this is my service implementation:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Person} from '../Model/Person';
import { identifierModuleUrl } from '@angular/compiler';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceService  {

  persons: Person[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  List = 'http://localhost:8080/todoangular/persons';

  getPersons() {
    return this.http.get<Person[]>(this.List);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Any error? What is going wrong in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is you're creating a singleton instance of your `ResolverService`. So that service is only being created once, with whatever state is in the ActivatedRouteSnapshot at the moment of its instantiation.

Take a look at the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) and you'll notice they only decorate the resolver with Injectable() (not providedIn: 'root'). Then they pass the ResolverService into the providers array for the module.